# How did the color green become associated with Esperanto?

Tags: culture

Green is everywhere in Esperantujo. It is rare to find an Esperanto-related website or item that does not contain that color.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The origin of the use of green can be traced back to Dr. Zamenhof.  In 1911, he wrote:

> About the origin of our green star I no longer remember very well.  It seems to me that Mr Geoghegan drew my attention to the colour green, and from that time I began publishing my works with a green cover. About one brochure, which I quite by chance published with a green cover, he remarked to me that this was the colour of his homeland, Ireland. Then it came into my head that we could well regard this colour as a symbol of Hope. As for the five-pointed star, it seems to me that Mr de Beaufront first printed it on his grammar-book. I liked this and I took it as an emblem. Afterwards by association of ideas the star appeared with the colour green. ([source](https://esperanto.ie/en/about/story-in-ireland-2/history-eai_1/))

So Zamenhof was influenced by [Richard Geoghegan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_H._Geoghegan), an Englishman of Irish descent, and he thought the color green might be associated with hope.

Comment: In Italian, green is the color associated with hope. In fact, we also say _verde speranza_ (_hope green_). I am not sure for which countries that association is true too.

Comment: Same in German.

Answer (score 4):

Green is commonly associated with the concept of hope. As *espero* (to hope) is the root of *Esperanto*, the connection seems obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

The house where Zamenhof was born had the address Zielona 6 ([source](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naski%C4%9Ddomo_de_Zamenhof) (in Esperanto)) in Poland. Zielona means ‘green’ in Polish, hence this might also be why green is associated with Esperanto.